# call spring bean from hibernate entity objects

Tags: spring, hibernate, design-patterns

Is it good practice to call spring bean from hibernate entity objects. I am working on below example.

```
abstract class Order {

    abstract void makePayment(PaymentObj);
}

//hibernate entity
class OrderType1 extends Order{
    //override
    makePayment() {

    }
}

// hibernate entity
class OrderType2 extends Order {
    // override
    makePayment() {

    }
}
```

Now in makePayment() method, I want to call payment gateway to process the payment. For that purpose, I need to call spring bean where payment gateway will be called. Is it good practice to call spring bean from hibernate entity?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, mixing entites and business logic abuses the MVC- pattern, you shall code your business logic in services

**EDIT**

you can create e.g a  PaymentService

```
public interface PaymentService {

      public void makePayment(Order order, PaymentObj paymentObj);
}

@Service
public class PaymentServiceImpl implements PaymentService {


      private SomeNeededBean someNeededBean;
      // Dao or repistory
      private SomeRepository someRepoistory;

      @Autowired
      public PaymentServiceImpl(SomeNeededBean someNeededBean, SomeRepoistory someRepoistory){
             this.someNeededBean = someNeededBean,
             this.someRepository= someRepository;
     }

      @Transactional
      public void makePayment(Order order, PaymentObj paymentObj){
         //some implemention;
     }

}
```

then just autowire your service into your controller and invoke makepayment in  controllers method

Comment: Then how should I handle this scenario?